# Displaying simple javascript enabled webpage within a Flex app?

Tags: html, apache-flex

I'm working on a Flex app that needs to display ads from third party vendors that come in the form of HTML docs containing javascript.  Are there any components available that can display such things?  It seems like we need a mini-browser that runs inside of Flex.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.  Unfortunately, Flex on its own doesn't do a particularly good job of rendering HTML, but there are some ways to work around this.  A post on Alex's Flex Closet does a good job of describing some options:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/html_and_flex_1.html

One component, aptly named HTMLComponent, may be of particular interest:

http://drumbeatinsight.com/