# Google Maps StreetView in Flex?

Tags: google-maps, flex4, google-street-view

I see that Google Maps Streetview is available in [Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanorama) . And there is no such service in [Flex/Flash API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/reference.html)

Is there any workaround for using that in Flex ? I really need this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed a HTML page (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332451/displaying-simple-javascript-enabled-webpage-within-a-flex-app)) to display the map...

Comment: i have implemented maps in flex and finished 90% of the application ... so , i don't think i will embed the map again in javascript...